# How to force console window to show up automatically when Blender starts

Tags: command-line

when I start Blender version 2.66a, the Blender loads, and shows up together with a console window.

Now when I start Blender version 2.77a, the Blender loads without a console window by default. I only can show the console window by clicking *Window -> Toggle System Console*

How to force the console window to show up together when Blender version 2.77a starts?

Thank you

Comment: Note that the steps will vary depending on your OS. For example, in OS X you would right click on Blender.app and "Show Package Contents", then navigate to "/MacOS/blender" and run that executable. There is another way using Automator to call this from a Dock shortcut (but I won't get into that now).

Comment: @Mentalist, do you know how do I "Show Package Contents" in Windows OS?

Comment: It doesn't work that way in Windows. When I wrote "steps will vary depending on OS", this is what I was talking about. Windows doesn't use application packages.

Answer (score 5):

Append `-con` to the command line arguments passed to `blender.exe`.

You can do so by modifying the properties of your favorite Blender shortcut and appending  `-con` in the **Target** text box.

The console window stays open then.

Comment: does not work in 2.90

Comment: Still works fine to me in 3.1.0, I doubt this was changed. Did you set up the shortcut properly?

Comment: I cannot even find the shortcut in the key bingings

Comment: It's not a key binding "shortcut", it's a shortcut you create to the Blender executable (on Windows) or just launch it with that command line parameter in another way.

Answer (score 1):

By your comments i suppose this is about windows. (would help to mention that in question as things like command line are very much os-specific)

One easy way to achieve this is to create .bat file, with content beind simply path to your blender install, like `C:\...\Blender.exe`. (Desktop > right click > new > Text file and then rename with replacing .txt with .bat) Then you can launch blender by running this "script" instead of blender shortcut, and command line should stay open.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a powershell script containing the details below ( of launching blender executable ) and put it on desktop. right click and run with powershell. Your powershell is the console now.

```
& "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\blender.exe"
```

- "&" is important to launch any executable.
- extension of powershell file is .ps1

[image: file content]
[image: Powershell option]